# Android testing that an alertDialog is shown in an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog, android-testing

Hello and thank you for taking the time to read this question.

I am trying to write an instrumentation test for an activity. The scenario is the following:

If on create of the activity the GPS is not enabled, an alertDialog should be shown to the user to suggest turning on the sensor. The check is performed by an utility class that checks the connectivity and shows the alertDialog if necessary. I want to be able to test in my class if the dialog is shown to the user.

Now for some code:

The activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    ...     
    Utils.checkGPSProvider(this);       
}
```

The Utility class:

```
public final class Utils {


private Utils() {

}

private static void createAlertDialog(final Context context, final String message, final String intentAction) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    final Intent callSettingIntent = new Intent(intentAction);

    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(message).setPositiveButton(POSITIVE_BUTTON,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                    context.startActivity(callSettingIntent);
                }
            });

    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(NEGATIVE_BUTTON, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    final AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alert.show();
}

public static void checkGPSProvider(final Context context) {
    String message;

    message = "GPS message";

    final LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (!mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

        createAlertDialog(context, message, android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    }
}
```

}

The test class:

```
public class UtilsTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyActivity> {

private MyActivity activity;

@Mock
LocationManager mlocManager;

public UtilsTest() {
    super(MyActivity.class);
}

public UtilsTest(Class<MyActivity> activityClass) {
    super(activityClass);
}

@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();

    activity = getActivity();

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

public void testWhenGPSIsDisabled_ShouldShowAlertDialog() {
    when(mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)).thenReturn(false);

    if (mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        Assert.fail("GPS should be disabled");
    }

(insert code here that should test that the alertDialog is shown)
}
}
```

I know that the Dialog class has an isShown() method but I do not know how to get the dialog reference to test the isShown method.

If there is any other necessary information I will try to provide it to you.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can return the reference of the `AlertDialog` from the method `createAlertDialog`

**example:**

```
private static AlertDialog createAlertDialog(final Context context, final String message, final String intentAction)
```

When you call this method you can then get the return reference value of the method same as your `checkGPSProvider` should also return AlertDialog.

**sample:**

```
    public static AlertDialog checkGPSProvider(final Context context) {
    String message;

    message = "GPS message";

    final LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (!mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

        return createAlertDialog(context, message, android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    }
}
```

And in your oncreate method of the activity create a Field for `AlertDialog` and instantiate with the `Utils.checkGPSProvider(this);`

**solution:**

```
 your_alert_dialog = Utils.checkGPSProvider(this);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I do not think that it is a good solution to change multiple classes only for testing purposes. I know the function works when used in the application but I want to have an automatic testing fail-safe mechanism just in case I start refactoring the class. I am looking for a solution which does not mean I have to change one or more of the classes I am testing just to get this going. Something that would involve the activity which I have a reference to in my test case.

Comment: @AndreiZafiu if that so then you for the createAlertDialog method you can put one more parameter which is a AlertDialog which is then passed from: activity - > checkGPSProvider - > createAlertDialog

Comment: I understand your point of view but I am looking for a solution that would be like an "Observer pattern". I want to test the required functionalities without modifing the code I am observing. Think of the case when you have to write the test but don't have access to the code you are testing and you cannot modify it.

Comment: @AndreiZafiu nope you cant get the instance of it even if you use observable pattern there is no way of getting it with out modifying it